# Linklist in hashmap java

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I'm making a doubly link in which the node are first inserted in the linklist and each node contains three  properties called `question_id(int)`, `Skip_logic(Boolean)` and `nextnode(int)`. Now if `skip_logic` is true the node checks for the nextnode Q_id and moves to that node with the particular id. Here is an example.

```
    --------  <---   ----------  <----   ---------  <-----   ---------
   | Node1  | ----> | Node 2   | -----> |  Node 3 | ----->  |  Node 4 |
    --------         ----------          ---------           ---------
```

Now the flow is like that after the insertion. Now if the node 1 contains `skip_logic=true`. It checks for the nextnode value. Say for instance it is 4, the flow becomes like this.

```
    --------         ----------  <----   ---------           ---------
   | Node1  | <---- | Node 2   | -----> |  Node 3 | ----->  |  Node 4 |
    --------         ----------          ---------           ---------
      ^                                                          ^
      |                                                          |
      ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now say for example the user wants to go from node 1 to node 2. The user again has to first find a node with that particular question id from the whole list. Now it doesn't cost much in this scenerio but if we have to take a jump from node 1 to node 1000, it takes a lot of searching cost and the link is broken and you have create a link too and add another pointer which contains link to both the paths but the searching cost is still there .I have implemented this part but the searching cost is something I want to avoid. I'm thinking of storing the linkedlist in the hashmap so that if the user wants to get to a particular node he can just enter the node and it will take it to a particular node. But the problem is I have to connect the nodes inside the hashmap with the other nodes and it would take some more memory I guess. So any ideas how I should go about doing that and if this approach is okay and I should go with it? And no this is not a homework.

Comment: You've got a few up votes, so it must be me being thick, but I can't see what you're trying to achieve. Can we see some use cases for this data structure. As code/sudo code, paragraphs of solid text are not clear (to me at least).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I got your explanation completely, but **[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** might be a good candidate for your requirements. It's a `HashMap` that also maintains a linked list of the entries in the order the keys were added to the map. So if you iterate over the `keySet`, you get the keys by insertion order.

Comment: Yeah i have checked it already but it doesn't follow the back node connected functionality..

Comment: @soldiershin What is "back node connected functionality"?

Comment: i meant that i am setting the next and the back pointer of any node at runtime.But hashmap stores the next and the back on the way they are inserted at the beginning..

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

The build-in Java implementation for SkipList is  **ConcurrentSkipListSet**